# I can't start the Node JS server on AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I launched instance on AWS under the ubuntu operating system, installed nodejs, cloned the git repository and launched it, but when I try to switch to a public ip I get the error: This site cannot provide a secure connection. The console displays this: crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated the node js application itself is running. Everything works on my computer.

Comment: You're probably trying to access it via HTTPS by clicking on the AWS console button that open the public IP of the EC2 machine and HTTPS by default.

Comment: indeed, but when I tried via http before I didn’t specify the port, now I specified IP:443 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely clicking on the "Open Address" button in the EC2 Console, which defaults to HTTPS:

[image: EC2 Console]

Simply copy your public address, open a new tab, and access it manually: it should work.